# Error while using ABySS to assemble SRA sequence

Tags: linux, makefile, bioinformatics, dna-sequence, genome

I'm having some trouble using ABySS to assemble reads downloaded from the NCBI SRA.

The command I've used is:

```
abyss-pe name=SRR530529_1 k=27 in=/home/bilalm/H_glaber_quality_filtering/AfterQC/good_reads/SRR530529.good.fq
```

But the assembly process had stopped with an error message ' **Abyss-fixmate: error: all reads are mateless.** '

The tail of the error message is:

```
Building the Burrows-Wheeler transform...
Building the character occurrence table...
Mateless   193637763  100%
Unaligned          0
Singleton          0
FR                 0
RF                 0
FF                 0
Different          0
Total      193637763

abyss-fixmate: error: All reads are mateless. This can happen when first and second read IDs do not match.
error: `SRR530529-3.hist': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/abyss-pe:561: recipe for target 'SRR530529-3.dist' failed
make: *** [SRR530529-3.dist] Error 1
make: *** Deleting file 'SRR530529-3.dist'
```

The ABySS version: 2.0.1
The fastq file size is: 52G

What has happened? What does mateless mean? My intentions were to clean the data and then assemble the naked mole rat genome using 4 fastq reads (SRR530529, SRR530530, SRR530531 & SRR530532) which I have downloaded from the NCBI SRA.

Cheers, Billy.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the abyss program to assemble paired-end reads, but you are feeding it only one file. If you have paired-end reads, each pair must have the same name so they can be recognized as a pair. Normally you would have the forward and reverse reads in two separated files, and would feed them like:

`abyss-pe name=SRR530529_1 k=27 in='reads1.fa reads2.fa'`

If you have single reads (mateless), then I'm not sure abyss will work, but you can try this:

`abyss-pe name=SRR530529_1 k=27 se=/home/bilalm/H_glaber_quality_filtering/AfterQC/good_reads/SRR530529.good.fq`

Comment: So I used the following code kindly recommend by @Lucia Balestrazzi `abyss-pe name=SRR530529_2_se k=27 se=/home/bilalm/H_glaber_quality_filtering/AfterQC/good_reads/SRR530529.good.fq`  = **/usr/bin/abyss-pe:506: receipe for target 'SRR530529_2_se_1.fa' failed
make: *** (SRR530529_2_se_1.fa] Killed** I dont think its possible to assemble single end reads/single reads using ABySS...